# How to get s3 buckets quota limit with via API call (go)

Tags: amazon-s3, bucket, quota

I know that the default is 100 buckets per account, but for cases where the limit is increased, I need to know it. I would like to use an API call for that. I can find the quota limit for other services while passing the Quota code (L-FE5A380F for NAT gateways for example) to 'servicequotas.Client.GetServiceQuota(ctx,&servicequotas.GetServiceQuotaInput{...})'
but with s3 buckets (L-DC2B2D3D), it does not work.
Help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is ‘does not work’? Does your machine blow up? Please clarify 

Comment: LOL... serviceQuotaOutput is nil.  In response I'm getting bad request 404

Comment: the quotaCode I'm using is 'L-DC2B2D3D and the serviceCode is 's3'